# Node.js async-functions executes on parallel?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

The code below is made to:

1. CONVERT some videos and store them on the folder of converted.
2. CONCATENATE the converted videos.
3. CLEAR the converted folder.

**BUT** currently, when executing the code, it concatenates while converting, and eventually throw an error. I need to execute each function with priority in his respective order.

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const { unlink } = require("fs").promises;

function start(index) {


  const path = `./files/${index}`;
  const ConvertedVideos=path+"/converted/*.mp4";
  const videos = glob.sync(path+"/videos/*.mp4");
  const outputnoaudio = path+"/outputnoaudio.mp4";




  //THIS IS THE ORDER OF EXECUTION

  await convertVideos()
  await withFfmpegConcatVideo()
  await clearConverted()



  //HERE THE DEFINITION OF EACH FUNCTION

  async function convertVideos() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      console.log('>>>Starting conversion!!!');
      const promises = videos.map(
        (video, index) => {
          var command = `ffmpeg -i ${video} -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 60 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 160k -strict experimental -f mp4 ./converted/${index}.mp4`;

          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (error) {
                console.warn(error);
              }
              resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
              console.log('Converted video', index);
            });
          });
        }
      )
      Promise.all(promises);
      resolve();
    })
  }

  async function withFfmpegConcatVideo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      console.log('Starting concatenation...');

      var converted = glob.sync(ConvertedVideos);

      console.log('There is ', converted.length, 'converted videos');

      if (converted.length > 0) {

        (async () =>
          await concat({
            output: outputnoaudio,
            videos: converted,
            transition: {
              name: 'fade',
              duration: 200
            }
          }))()
      }
      resolve(console.log('Conversion finished'));
    })
  }


  async function clearConverted() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      const converted =
        glob.sync(ConvertedVideos)

      if (converted.length === 0)
        return Promise.resolve([])

      const promises =
        converted.map(v => unlink(v).then(_ => {
          v
        }))

      Promise.all(promises).then('Clean done.')
      resolve();
    })
  }
}

start(1);
```

I want to keep clean and reusable code.
May you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the code thanks to your comments and found this solution.

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const concat = require('ffmpeg-concat');
const {
  unlink
} =
require("fs").promises;
const exec = require("child_process").exec;

async function start(index){



  const path = `./files/${index}`;
  const pathToConverted = `${path}/converted`;
  const videos = glob.sync(`${path}/[0-99]/videoKeywords/[0-99]/*output.mp4`);
  const output = `${path}/output.mp4`;
  const outputmuted = `${path}/outputmuted.mp4`;




   async function clearConverted() {

    await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      console.log('Starting cleaning...');
      const converted = glob.sync(`${pathToConverted}/*.mp4`)

      if (converted.length === 0)
        return Promise.resolve([])

      const promises =
        converted.map(v => unlink(v).then(_ => {
          console.log("   File Deleted");
          v
        }))

      await Promise.all(promises).then(async () => await console.log('Clean done.'))

      resolve()
    })
  }




async function convertVideos() {
    await new Promise(async (resolve) => {

      console.log('>>>Starting conversion of', videos.length, 'files!!!');


      for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

        let video = videos[i];

        var command = `ffmpeg -i ${video} -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 60 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 160k -strict experimental -f mp4 ${pathToConverted}/${i}.mp4`;

        await new Promise((resolve) => {
          exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
              console.warn(error);
            }
            resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
            console.log('  Converted video', i);
          });
        });
      }
      resolve();
    }).then(async () => await console.log('Conversion finished!!!'))
  }




 async function clearConverted() {

    await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      console.log('Starting cleaning...');
      const converted = glob.sync(`${pathToConverted}/*.mp4`)

      if (converted.length === 0)
        return Promise.resolve([])

      const promises =
        converted.map(v => unlink(v).then(_ => {
          console.log("   File Deleted");
          v
        }))

      await Promise.all(promises).then(async () => await console.log('Clean done.'))

      resolve()
    })
  }
}
start(0);
```

Notice that this implementation of `function convertVideos()` execute conversion sequentially asynchronous which means that it converts one file by step.
On the previous implementation of this function, the execution is in parallel, which is optimal for a few videos to convert if you have several cores.

If you have any code suggestions to process a higher volume of videos at the same time, please feel free to support.

Answer (score 1):

Your `start` function doesn't look correct because you are missing the `async` operator.

For clarity, I suggest treating this more like a C file and create an `async function main() {}` where you call and `await` your three functions.

In your `convertVideos` function, you are calling `Promise.all()`, but you aren't awaiting that. Note that `Promise.all()` actually returns a promise too, and you must await that, but in order for you to await it, the surrounding function must also have the `async` keyword. I see the same problem in the `clearConverted` function.

Try awaiting your `Promise.all` calls, and see if that helps fix your problem.

In fact, your `convertVideos` function seems to be wrapping everything up in a Promise, and I don't think you need that. Try this:

```
function convertVideos() {
    console.log('>>>Starting conversion!!!');
    const promises = videos.map(
        (video, index) => {
            var command = `ffmpeg -i ${video} -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 60 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 160k -strict experimental -f mp4 ./converted/${index}.mp4`;

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (error) {
                       console.warn(error);
                    } 
                resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
                console.log('Converted video', index);
            });
        });
      });


    // Notice that you can return this promise from Promise.all.
    // The caller can then await this promise that will let you know when
    // all the videos are converted.
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: I found useful your answer, I just fix it and it works!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
withFfmpegConcatVideo().then(() => clearConverted());
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I want to avoid to use **.then()** so, the expected code must look like`await withFfmpegConcatVideo(); await clearConverted();`